# An error occurs in typescript when Optional Chaining is specified as a variable

Tags: typescript

I encountered the following error when I wrote code using 'Optional Changing'.

```
type Foo = {
  b?: number
}

const foo:Foo = {}

if (foo?.b) {
  console.log(foo.b / 10)
}
```

```
type Foo = {
  b?: number
}

const foo:Foo = {}

const flag = foo?.b

if (flag) {
  // ERROR: Object is possibly 'undefined'
  console.log(foo.b / 10)
}
```

The first code is no problem.

However, the second code will cause an error.

Why does this error occur?

Also, I would like to know how to avoid the error by writing the second code!

Comment: if(foo?.b) {...} would work, but that's not the way you want it to work, right?

Comment: `flag` is just a variable for typescript, it 'forgets' that it is initialized from `foo?.b`

Comment: Yes! I'd prefer to use "const flag = foo?.b".

Comment: @ddd you can use `foo.b! / 10` to inform ts that `foo.b` will be defined at that time

Comment: @D Pro I understand that type inference is not working in the second way. But is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript does not track related variables as stated in this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30539. This ticket also has a link to a larger discussion on how control flow analysis works in TypeScript. Put simply, in the if block, the `foo.b` is not the same as `flag`.

What you may do here, instead:

```
type Foo = {
  b?: number
}

const foo:Foo = {}

const flag = foo?.b

if (flag) {
  console.log(flag / 10)
}
```